# KVM hypervisor remote access without libvirt

Tags: kvm-virtualization, remote-access, libvirt

I am a newbie in the area of Linux KVM virtualization. Can anybody help how to connect to my KVM hypervisor from a remote Linux machine without using LibVirt or any other third party library. I have searched for this but all the results that i got was using libvirt or commands related to it. I am not allowed to use any third party library and need to take the backup of my KVM from remote machine.

Can you also tell me why a deamon is required in KVM when it is not required in VMware ESXI?

Are there any KVM API's present for taking the backup of VM's running on KVM from a remote machine (without using libvirt)? This backup need to be take at different levels such as VM level, Disk level and file level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KVM is a hypervisor, not a management stack, so if you want to manage it you either log in to the host console, or use management tools like libvirt. Comparing it to ESXi is not very correct in this sense - ESXi is packed with daemons and additional tools, and this is exactly the functionality libvirt provides (actually, it provides more), so I can't see why you cannot use a common Linux based library that is designed to answer your every need on a single host setup.

KVM has the basic command line tools to start/stop VMs, and to interact with the VM you can connect to qemu monitor, however, all of this is much easier and intuitive with libvirt as well.

BTW, using libguestfs you can read the guest filesystem from the host, and take selective backups. And with libvirt managing VM snapshots and lifecycle is also much easier than without it.

Comment: thanks for the reply dyasny, I know and i had done the same using libvirt. but in current context I have bound to not to use libvirt. 


the design is I need to take backup of different VM's running on KVM hypervisor from a remote machine without using any deamon process in my KVM server (i.e. it has to be agent less) for different levels (such as VM level, disk level, file level etc) without creating any temporary file.

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't consider using libvirt as an agent - it's a standard part of the distribution and not a 3rd party product. you need to understand that on ESXi, every tool is just as much of an addon as libvirt is on Linux. Frankly, in all my years dealing with KVM I haven't seen any production setu that used kvm only, without any management wrappers around it

Comment: Libvirt install its deamon as libvirtd in the host server so that the remote machine and communicate with it. the design that i am working on strictly says agentless working is requierd thats why I need to work on KVM alone. Are there any API's for KVM (like what libvirt or Qemu use internally to intarct with KVM) so that I may directly use them.

Comment: like I said - qemu monitor. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor

Comment: @Dr.Death You should fix the design, then.